# Picasso: UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication not enabled for client

Tags: android, picasso

I am using Picasso 2.5.2 in my application. It works well, but can't load pictures from one of third-party server. When I try to load pictures from this site I get this error:

```
java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication not enabled for client
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:98)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:196)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:132)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:101)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:179)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:63)
at com.jakewharton.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader.load(OkHttp3Downloader.java:136)
at com.squareup.picasso.NetworkRequestHandler.load(NetworkRequestHandler.java:47)
at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:206)
at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)
```

When I open this image in browser it load successfully. URL looks like `http://somesite.com/path/to/file/123456.jpg`. Is it Picasso bug? How to fix it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is it Picasso bug?

I don't think so. OkHttp appears to block non-SSL communications by default. I haven't done a plain-text HTTP request with OkHttp in ages, but that's what I'm seeing from my examination of the code that relates to that error message.

> How to fix it?

Use an `https` URL.

If some diabolical madman is threatening to blow up a small city unless you use plain `http`, configure the `OkHttpClient` via its `Builder`, including a call to `connectionSpecs()` to indicate what sorts of HTTP connections you are willing to support. For example:

`.connectionSpecs(Arrays.asList(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS, ConnectionSpec.CLEARTEXT))`

would allow "modern TLS" (not exactly certain what qualifies) and plain HTTP.

Then, use that `OkHttpClient` for Picasso, as well as for anything that you are doing directly using OkHttp.

Comment: On my side, I resolve my issue writing this line in manifest's `application` tag `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

Answer (score 2):

I have searched your problems. And I think you have problem with okhttp3 like the issue at https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/498 - problem with authentication connection. You can try to work around by custom your downloader of Picasso by:

```
// create Picasso.Builder object
Picasso.Builder picassoBuilder = new Picasso.Builder(context);

// let's change the standard behavior before we create the Picasso instance
// for example, let's switch out the standard downloader for the OkHttpClient
picassoBuilder.downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(new OkHttpClient()));
// or you can try 

(picassoBuilder.downloader(  
    new OkHttpDownloader(
        UnsafeOkHttpClient.getUnsafeOkHttpClient()
    )
);)

// Picasso.Builder creates the Picasso object to do the actual requests
Picasso picasso = picassoBuilder.build();
```

Now you can use your picasso  to load your image.

```
picasso  
   .load(linktoimage)
   .into(imageView3);
```

Comment: Bear in mind that the `UnsafeOkHttpClient` implementation that is floating around teh internets is a security disaster and will get you banned from the Play Store. Do not use code that blindly accepts all SSL certificates.

Comment: I only discover your problem. I think problem with connection okhttp. If you find out the problem, share your solution (you can try with solution fo @CommonsWare). Thanks.